# Updating the sample variance, sample by sample

Tags: variance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computation of new standard deviation using old standard deviation after change in dataset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24878/computation-of-new-standard-deviation-using-old-standard-deviation-after-change)

I know the sample variance of n samples and its mean and n itself. Now I would like to add one more sample so I have n + 1. Is there a way how to add the sample without recalculation the whole term. (computational efficient). Approximation would be fine too.

Comment: Do you also know the size of each sample?

Comment: I believe you're looking for an online algorithm for calculating variance. See [this link on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm).

Comment: I assumed that "sample" referred to a single observation. If that's incorrect, disregard my previous comment.

Comment: a given sample at the beginning and than one sample each time.

Comment: Max, you did answer my question. You could answer the usual way and I could accept it. (otherwise how to close this question?)

Comment: For more information about such "online" approaches to updating statistical summaries, look at the threads tagged with [tag:online].

Comment: Its not a duplicate the proposed link is about replaceing an observation, while this is about adding an observation.