# Variance when we add a new point in the data set

Tags: variance

variance of 10 data set is 20, and mean is 3. If we add new observation 3 (say). Then total observations are 11. Can we find variance for these 11 observations?

What I did so far...
sum of x_i = 10*3 = 30
sum of [${x_i}^2$ divided by 10] - 9  = 20
or ${x_i}^2$ = 290

now, a new observation added. now n = 11. What is the new variance

Comment: [Updating standard deviation without set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457174/updating-standard-deviation-without-set)

Comment: [Computation of new standard deviation using old standard deviation after change in dataset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24878/computation-of-new-standard-deviation-using-old-standard-deviation-after-change)