# Updating of OLS regression estimates when one data point is changed

Tags: regression, least-squares, online-algorithms

How do I estimate the new slope and intercept if I'm given a 'updated' data instance?

For example I have a regression equation y = 1x + 0.5 and this is learned with a data set of 10 data instances with feature x = {9,22,34,36,38,49,59,78,80,85},

Let's say one of the instances (49,50) (60 is the true y label for this instance) is changed to (49,60). How would this affect the new equation?

Comment: I doubt such an updating is possible, but cannot you just re-estimate your parameters?

Comment: This is related to online algorithms. Search this site.

Comment: @ott such an updating is certainly possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intuition for recursive least squares](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66950/intuition-for-recursive-least-squares)