# Bounds on coefficients of linear regression when changing data

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

Are there any general results on bounds for linear regression model coefficients if we change the data set? For example, if I learn a model with a few data points less, what will happen to the model coefficients?

I have tried to look at the algebra, but the design matrix inversion involved in finding the model coefficients seems to "block" finding useful bounds.

Note: this is not a "sensitivity analysis" question. The changes in the data could be "big".

Comment: The method of sequential updating I describe at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6920/efficient-online-linear-regression/6923#6923 also works in reverse.  From that you can deduce bounds for the changes in regression estimates as a function of the data that are added or deleted.

Comment: Influence functions tell you the exact change in a parameter estimate when a particular observation is left out.